# Compile hunspell with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, compiler-errors, hunspell

I need a spellcheck tool for my MS C++ (MFC) project. It looks like hunspell is a good choice. However, I found it difficult to compile with visual studio. Can someone help?

Here is what I have done:
I downloaded hunspell from sourceforge, the version is 1.2.14. Unzipped it.
Created an empty solution in visual studio and added the projects into it. The project files are under win_api directory.
Then I tried to compile it, and got a bunch of errors.

By the way, my operating system Vista (x64).

Please help.

---

Thanks for the reply.
Today, I tried it on a Windows XP (x86) system and it compiled without errors.

### The error message with Vista x64 was: error c2552: non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list. It is for file 'utf_info.cxx'. It's strange that XP x86 works fine.

It seems the version 1.2.12 works fine, for both 32 and 64-bit machines.

Comment: If you don't provide a short listing of the errors you are encountering, i'm going to vote for this question to be close/removed.

Comment: Yeah, we need to know what the actual errors you're getting are in order to be able to help. The [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/) seems to indicate it will compile fine if you have the Windows SDK installed.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a [known bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3152036&group_id=143754&atid=756395).

There's now a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3154261&group_id=143754&atid=756397) available, which has been integrated into the CVS as of January 13, 2011. Make sure that you grab the latest copy of the source.